# Add a Function to an addEventListener Refactoring

Tags: javascript, function, dom, refactoring, addeventlistener

### Refactor

Somehow i can't make it work, the
code works without the refactoring. I commented out the part in where
i have tried it .
The function should do the same as exactly without it.
Thanks everyone in advance, maybe i do something wrong, as i come from
python language to javascript.

**Somehow it doesn't take the input in the function for p1 or p2 instead it's
player = 1 but p1 still remain 0 or p2 for example**

```js
const player1btn = document.querySelector('.p1Button')
const player2btn = document.querySelector('.p2Button')
const p1score = document.querySelector('.p1Score')
const p2score = document.querySelector('.p2Score')
const resetbtn = document.querySelector('.reset')
const playto = document.querySelector('#playto')

p1 = 0
p2 = 0
player1btn.disabled = false
player2btn.disabled = false

// function players(player,playerscore,playto,playerbutton) {
//     player++
//     playerscore.innerText = p1
//     if (player === parseInt(playto.value)){
//          playerscore.classList.add('has-text-success')
//         if (playerbutton == player1btn){
//             player2btn.classList.add('has-text-danger')
//         }
//         else{
//             player1btn.classList.add('has-text-danger')
//         }
//         player1btn.disabled = true
//         player2btn.disabled = true
//     }
// }

//     player1btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
//     players(p1,p1score,playto,player1btn)
//     })

//     player2btn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
//     players(p2,p2score,playto,player2btn)
// })


player1btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    p1++
    p1score.innerText = p1
    if (p1 === parseInt(playto.value)){
        p1score.classList.add('has-text-success')
        p2score.classList.add('has-text-danger')
        player1btn.disabled = true
        player2btn.disabled = true
    }
        
})

player2btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    p2++
    p2score.innerText = p2
    if (p2 === parseInt(playto.value)){
        p2score.classList.add('has-text-success')
        p1score.classList.add('has-text-danger')
        player1btn.disabled = true
        player2btn.disabled = true
    }
})
```